# P4Python : AttributeError: type object 'P4' has no attribute 'Map'

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping, perforce, p4python

Here is the code I use:

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception    
mp = P4.Map()
```

And here's the error I get:

> mp = P4.Map() AttributeError: type object 'P4' has no attribute 'Map'

WHY?
According to P4Python manuals such class method should construct a new Map object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you import `class P4` from `P4.py`. Map is another class from P4.py. See source code: https://github.com/rptb1/p4python/blob/master/P4.py

You should try this:

```
import P4
mp = P4.Map()
```